# Unexpected T_FUNCTION?

Tags: php

I've question about solving in php version 5.2.7, where i get an error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION in /home/ ... /mainMenu.php on line 56. The code is

```
class MainMenu {
    ...
    private static function toRec($arr) {
        ...

        usort($newArr, function($a, $b) {//this was line 56
            return $a['nav_order'] - $b['nav_order'];
        });
        ...
    }
    ...

}
```

What is alternative for php 5.2?

Thank you

Comment: Create the function and name it separately, and then call it `usort($newArr, 'myFunctionName');`

Comment: There are several examples in [the usort() docs](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Your question doesn't give enough of your code to make an authorive answer. However, that error in PHP usually means you haven't properly ended a previous statement with a `;`, or other function ending `)`, etc. Check your statement endings.

Comment: @PenguinCoder Unless you know that PHP 5.2 doesn't support anonymous functions.  And there is enough there to go off of.

Comment: @PenguinCoder In this case it is the use of an anonymous function in PHP 5.2, which the OP is aware of.

Answer (score 8):

As you've discovered, the inline function syntax is only valid in PHP 5.3 an higher. It is not available in PHP 5.2.

The alternative is to specify the name of a function instead, as a string, and then declare the function separately with that name. This is documented fairly well in the [usort() manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php), so I won't go into detail here.

You can also use `create_function()`. This may be the closest way to make your PHP 5.2 code look like 5.3 visually, but I would strongly recommend against this for a number of reasons.

Finally, I would very strongly recommend upgrading away from 5.2. I know there are cases where this is difficult, but that fact is that PHP 5.2 was declared end of life more than two years ago; it has not had any security updates in that time, and there are some big holes in it. If you're still stuck on 5.2 then you are falling further and further behind the curve; even 5.3 will be end-of-life in the near future, as 5.5 is due out fairly soon now.

Answer (score 2):

[Anonymous functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) are available only since PHP 5.3, so you may either declare function and use it just once (I'd go this way), or use [`create_function()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.create-function.php):

```
usort($newArr, create_function( '$a, $b', 'return $a[\'nav_order\'] - $b[\'nav_order\'];'));
```

But this will create function each time you'll execute piece of code, so try not to use it in a loop. :)

Comment: I want to upvote the "But this will create function each time you'll execute piece of code, so try not to use it in a loop. :)" part of that =D

Comment: @Jon I'm sorry I don't get what are you trying to say :-/

Comment: No worries, I thought it was funny before you changed the last sentence to what it is now, back when you said something like "But this will create a new function every time you execute it, so I wouldn't go this way" =]

Answer (score 0):

correct syntex for the us usort is

```
usort($a, "FUNCTION_NAME");

function FUNCTION_NAME(){
}
```

Comment: @MadaraUchiha - well, the question did specifically ask for an alternative that works in 5.2, so this answer is correct. (it could do with being longer to explain that point, but it is correct)

Answer (score 0):

What you are using is lambda/ anonymous function which is supported in PHP 5.3 and above
to make it work for PHP 5.2 use as following

```
class MainMenu {
    ...
    private static function toRec($arr) {
        ...

        usort($newArr, array('MainMenu','someFunction'));
        ...
    }
    ...
   private static function someFunction ($a, $b)
   {
     ....
   }

}
```

Comment: That doesn't work. It will call `someFunction` during the first call, and send the result to usort.