# PHP error syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION in

Tags: php, wordpress

/CustomPostType.php on line 165

```
// Initialise class variables as blank
        $metaKeys = $this->get_meta_keys();
        foreach( $metaKeys as $key )
            if( !empty( $key ) )
                $this->$key = null;

        $this->ID = null;
```

The below code is what fixed the syntax error.

```
    public function get_meta_keys( $objectName) {
     $getClassVars = get_class_vars( $objectName ); 
     return array_keys( $getClassVars);
```

}

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unexpected T\_FUNCTION?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16015286/unexpected-t-function)

Comment: This is nothing to do with PHP 5.2, and everything to do with some strange syntax on the line in question whch probably should be `$getClassVars = get_class_vars( $objectName );`

Comment: Sorry guys i am not the developer of the code this was just throw on my lap to try fix. - thanks for your comments, every bit helps!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is syntax error in the code. It should be like this :

```
public function get_meta_keys( $objectName) {
         $getClassVars = get_class_vars( $objectName ); 
         return array_keys( $getClassVars);
}
```

Point to correct :

- Correct function signature. Add argument in the function get_meta_keys().

Answer (score 0):

Err, your code doesn't even look like it validates to me.

```
public function get_meta_keys( $objectName ) {
    $getClassVars = get_class_vars( $objectName );
    return array_keys( $getClassVars() );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put semicolon at the end of the function call and also you need to format your code first.

```
public function get_meta_keys( ) 
{
     $getClassVars = get_class_vars( $objectName );
     return array_keys( $getClassVars() );
}
```